# How can i rotate an object on one of the axis but non stop?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The problem is that it's rotating it once.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MakeTwoPoints3D : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 3f;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        float degrees = 90;
        Vector3 to = new Vector3(degrees, 0, 0);

        transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(transform.rotation.eulerAngles, to, Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
}
```

What i want to do is if i give as degrees 90 or 20 or any angle it will rotate in jumps of the given degree. If i give 360 it will make one 360 rotation if i give any less then 360 then to add some wait time between each rotation.
For example if i give a degree of 90 it should rotate each time in 90 degrees with a half of seconds wait between each rotation.

The problem is that now it will rotate once only by 90 degrees. And i want it to rotate non stop.

Comment: I imagine there's lots of tutorials on doing this, e.g. https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/spinning-cube

Comment: `while(true) {Update();}`

Answer (score 1):

To rotate around Y by one degree every frame

```
void OnUpdate()
{
   var p = transform.eulerAngles;
   p.y += 1; // rotate around Y by 1 degree every frame
   transform.eulerAngles = p;
}
```